# Mongoose Object Multi Search Problem (Object in Object)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

[image: mongose find error]

[image: my search code]

Hello, I want to quickly list the faulty ones in the array with mongoose.I couldn't find a result.

```js
       const locationValidate = await iUzmanlıklar.find(
            {
                $or: [
                  { mainName: { $regex: searchRgx, $options: "i" } },
                  
                 
                  
                  
                 
                  
                 
                ],
                $and:[
                    { mainCategoryId: _referenceCategory },
                
                    
                    
                  
                ]
                
              },'specialtyId translations isList mainName referenceCategory uuid authorizedCategories');
```

I want to send a single request to get quick results.

Comment: What are you trying to acheive?

Comment: I just want to list the wrong ones in the translated content.(translations.XX.error = true)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fetch all the translations where error is true for a particular `mainCategoryId`, you can use the following code:

```js
try {
    const locationValidate = await iUzmanliklar.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                mainCategoryId: _referenceCategory
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                translationsArray: { $objectToArray: "$translations" }
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: "$translationsArray"
        },
        {
            $match: {
                "translationsArray.v.error": true
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                translation: "$translationsArray.v"
            }
        }
    ]);
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
}
```

The `'translations.$': 1` projection is used to only include the matched translation(s) in the result. The `locationValidate` should be an array that can be further processed or logged as needed.

Comment: There is no error in translate.(translate.error does not exist,transalte.en.error || translate.pt.error exits)

Comment: @SuhatAkbulak I've updated my code. Please help to check it.